# JavaScript Button not work at one section

Tags: javascript, button

On the site I use a pop-up modal window. In all sections on the site it is used and works fine, but in one of the sections it does not work, why is that? Global section:

```
 <!-- Sidebar  -->
 <nav id="sidebar">
     <div id="dismiss">

     </div>

     <div class="sidebar-header">
         <h3>Menu</h3>
     </div>

    this is menu
     </ul>

 </nav>
```

My button:

```
<button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn-yellow" data-ng-if="user.accessToken">Open sidebar</button>
```

And in JS file at first line:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $("#sidebar").mCustomScrollbar({
        theme: "minimal"
    });

    $('#dismiss, .overlay').on('click', function () {
        $('#sidebar').removeClass('active');
        $('.overlay').removeClass('active');
    });

    $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
        $('#sidebar').addClass('active');
        $('.overlay').addClass('active');
        $('.collapse.in').toggleClass('in');
        $('a[aria-expanded=true]').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
    });
});
```

Why does it work in all sections, but does not work in one? What could be the problem?

Comment: Do you have the same `id="sidebarCollapse"` in multiple sections? IDs have to be unique, you should use classes for elements that repeat.

Comment: yes, i have the same `id="sidebarCollapse", but in different sections use different javascripts files

Comment: The JavaScript files are irrelevant. Are they in the same HTML page?

Comment: They all connected at main blade template